# Using your own backend with AWS Amplify authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm investigating the possibility of using AWS amplify for my authentication on an app ( https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication )

What I'm wondering is whether I can use my own back-end for the application. I.E a node API server connected to a DB that is NOT hosted on AWS for example, but on some dedicated box somewhere.

I would like to use amplify methods for auth `Auth.signUp` and `Auth.signUp` within my front-end. But then assuming I'm developing a game - when a user calls `POST getItems` for example I direct them to my non AWS backend. Perhaps passing along the results of `Auth.currentCredentials()` along in the API call in order to fetch the current tokens which could validate those tokens somehow?

The idea being I can then use their e-mail ( or some sort of other unique user ID ) extracted from the validated JWT in order to store user based records against on my own managed DB.

I would like to avoid going the full S3 route of API gateway, lambda, dynamo etc if possible whilst starting off, but maintain the ability to progressively move over when necessary!

Comment: AWS Amplify auth uses cognito user pools to manage users. For extra data control you would need to sync data and store it into dynamodb. Or use custom attributes on the users in the user pool, but if you do that you are limited on how many fields you can add.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here sorry. I understand the mechanisms that amplify uses. What i'm wondering is whether I can use Amplify for auth, but host my own backend not on AWS ( But still authenticate it's a valid user etc )

Comment: If that is the use case then why Amplify Auth. its built with the intent of using cognito as user pool and makes it a quick step to implement. Depending if you are using amplify with angular, react, vue etc, you should just implement your own authenticator. There are many examples out there.

Comment: Hi @does_not_compute have you found any solution to your question? I am currently looking for the same thing and hardly can find any documentation for this case. Is it even appropriate to use Amplify Auth (Cognito) with use pool against your own back-end? 

I was planning to get the tokens from Cognito, and then use those to validate access token at the back-end and access the API there, but not sure if this approach is fine. I also asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73402640/what-is-the-authentication-flow-for-spa-react-amplify-cognito-backend-i, please share what you think

Comment: I'm afraid I decided to just use a different auth solution @ServerKhalilov. My current stack is still react app frontend, and node backend, however I use auth0 which does exactly what I explained in the original post (allows my frontend to send a JWT, which the backend can authenticate then extract metadata such as user email).

Comment: @does_not_compute I see, thanks a lot for getting back to my comment, I also used Auth0 in such a way for a different project and it worked just fine. Pretty puzzled with Cognito, though :)