# What is the authentication flow for SPA (React) + Amplify + Cognito + Backend? Is Amplify Cognito integration only for serverless apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

**What I have?**

A client (React) and a backend (PHP) with a simple authentication flow: the client exchanges the `id token` with the back-end and keeps it in `localStorage`.

**What I want to do?**

I want to change the above approach to authentication with Cognito, to support Google Sign In and a sign-in against the user pool.

***Important:*** I do not want to use Cognito Hosted UI or Amplify pre-built auth components. I already have UI for the authentication pages on my client, and I want to hook up the authentication with Cognito to that UI.

**How am I doing it?**

On the client, I am using Amplify library to implement the authentication against Cognito, as it provides all the functionality I need.

In the process of signing in on the client, the Amplify library gets all the tokens from Cognito in the following form:

```
{
   AuthenticationResult: ""
   AccessToken: "…"
   ExpiresIn: 3600
   IdToken: "..."
   RefreshToken: "..."
   TokenType: "Bearer"
   ChallengeParameters: {}
}
```

Apart from that, the client receives a user object from the user pool with all the attributes.

Now this is a step I have questions about - *what should be done next?*

I realize that the client is already logged in to Cognito. However, the client still needs to call my own backend API for accessing the required resources.

I came up with the following options:

1. After signing in, the client could send the access token to the back-end, where the token can be verified, and, if valid, the back-end will respond with some kind of a flag that indicates to the client that it can call the API now.
2. After signing in, the client could send the access token to the back-end, back-end verifies the token, and issues a new token to access the back-end API only, which the client then stores and uses it against back-end endpoints.

I really got lost in Amplify documentation, and not even sure if I got everything right here. Is Amplify actually intended to be used only for serverless apps, or my case is also a valid scenario? If so, please let me know what would be the best practice here, and which approach should I take.

Thank you!

Comment: Amplify is great for helping you build full-stack apps with AWS as it's backend services, such as accessing DataStore (DynamoDB) and others. It seems like you're only using Cognito to purely use Google Sign in if i'm not mistaken? If that's the case you're probably better off using something like next-auth to handle the google sign in

Comment: Thank you for the response, @elguapo. Yes, what I want from Amplify is to have a fast implementation of social sign-ins (Google, Facebook, etc.) + the possibility to use the User Pool (I use it as well). I need this to work in order to reuse User Pool in case I want to have multiple applications to have the same user database. The problem is that I don't see any other way to connect my React Client + Own back-end to Cognito authentication flow, apart from the approach I mentioned in the question.

Comment: If that's the case the best way to do it is to use Cognito to generate your JWT token, send it to your backend and store it, then use that same JWT token to authenticate your requests. You'd have to use API gateway as well I believe to achieve this. Cognito is designed to be used with other AWS backend services, so in order to avoid all these extra steps, it would be easier to use Amplify as a full service backend afaik...